# How do I write a method to calculate the mode of an array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, mode

I'm trying to write a method to calculate the mode of an array.  I'm trying to write it with only two arrays.  For some reason, the output I get is the size of the array --> 100.  So far this is what I have:

```
public static int mode(int[ ] grades) {
  int mode[ ] = new int [101];
  int value = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
    mode[grades[ i ] ]++;  //this part really confuses me and I don't know how to interpret this.
                           //can someone please explain this to me too.  I know this is the only...
  int max = 0;             //...way to get it with 2 arrays.

  for(int i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
    max = mode[ i ];
    value = i;
  }

  return value;
}
```

Comment: kindly explain your question in detail so that we can he lp you.. I am not getting it..

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Here, take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

grades can be in the range `[0,100]`, which is 101 numbers (hence the size of 101).

```
for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
    mode[grades[i]]++;
```

`grades[i]` gets the number at slot `i`.  Let's say that's 85.  This give us:
`mode[85]++`, which increments the number of times we've seen the grade 85.

After this is complete, we iterate through `mode` and see which slot has the highest value, this value cooresponds to the mode, since `mode` simply keeps track of the number of times we encounter each score.

However, the second part is incorrect, you only want to update `max`, `value` if the current element is `> max`, ie:

```
int max = 0;           
for(int i = 0; i< 101; i++)
{
     if (mode[i] > max)
     {
         max = mode[i];
         value = i;
     }
}
```